# Is printf buffering part of the C standard?

Tags: c, io, printf

I am writing a program in C on Linux where various things will be written to `stdout` via `printf`. Naturally, I would try to minimize the IO calls and buffer all the information and then pass it to a single print call. However, through testing, I have discovered that `printf` does buffering of its own until it reaches a `'\n'`.
My question is, can I be certain that all `printf` implementations do this, or is glibc just optimized? Is it reliable to trust `printf` to do the buffering for me?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thank you.

Comment: While not authoritative, the wording [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams) kind of implies that it partially is. `stdin` and `stdout` must be fully buffered unless connected to an interactive device. `stderr` is never fully buffered.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In fact it *is* provisioned by the standard, so I take my first comment back: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.3p7

Comment: I would say it's safe to assume that `printf` is buffered.  I would say that any attempt to bundle up characters in one's own, explicit buffer, so as to artificially minimize the number of actual `printf` calls, would be a huge and unnecessary waste of time.  (There might be compilers with tiny C libraries for embedded platforms where there's no actual buffering.  Are you programming for an environment like that?  You said Linux, so I guess not.)

Comment: @SteveSummit There are unbuffered microcontroller implementations. But on the kind of low-end systems where such applies, it's considered very bad practice to use `stdio.h` anyway, because functions like printf will slaughter all memory and execution speed available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard allows both unbuffered and buffered streams. The relevant part is C17 7.21.3/3:

> When a stream is *unbuffered*, characters are intended to appear from the source or at the destination as soon as possible. Otherwise characters may be accumulated and transmitted to or from the host environment as a block. When a stream is *fully buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is *line buffered*, characters are intended to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a new-line character is encountered.

This is typically a decision depending on the OS rather than the standard library implementation. Most hosted console-based OS use the line buffered implementation where `\n` will "flush the buffer". Otherwise an explicit call to `fflush(stdout)` will always do that (and it's strictly speaking more portable).

An example of an unbuffered system is limited "bare metal" microcontroller one, where `stdout` is an UART and there's no hardware buffers to store a lot of characters.

Comment: I would also add that whether an output stream is fully buffered by default depends on whether the device is "interactive", the definition of which is implementation-defined.

Comment: @sj95126 "Interactive" is some C standard nonsense term though. The kind of unbuffered microcontroller systems I mentioned can be plenty interactive with a terminal on a PC side. Truth is that the people who wrote this text, which possibly goes back all the way to Dennis Ritchie, pretty much only had Unix in mind.

Comment: Perhaps it's antiquated, but the phrasing is still in the standard as recently as the C2x draft. I was just pointing out that it's in there, is all.

Comment: @sj95126 Yeah, the stream chapter in the same section goes "Input and output, whether to or from physical devices such as terminals and tape drives". I have personally only seen tape drives on a technical museum. Unless maybe it refers to the good old dot matrix printers, they were still being used in the 90s...